# Proving susceptibility in Lorentz Model satisy Kramers-Kronig relations

Tags: optics

My instructor asked me to prove that the real and imaginary parts of the electric susceptibility derived from Lorentz Model satisfy the Kramers-Kronig relations using the residue theorem. The problem is that my complex calculus is pretty rusty and I do not know which poles contribute exactly. There are 5 poles in total 4 from the susceptibility and 1 from the denominator(see the expression please). I took the integral using the principal value option in Mathematica and it turned out not as expected. Is this analytically tractable easily?

$$ \chi(\omega) = \frac{\omega_{p}^2}{(\omega_0^2-\omega^2)+i\gamma\omega} $$

The Kramers-Kronig relations are

$$ \chi_r(\omega) = \frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\bar{\omega} \frac{\chi_i(\bar{\omega})}{\bar{\omega}-\omega} $$
$$ \chi_i(\omega) = -\frac{1}{\pi} P \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\bar{\omega} \frac{\chi_r(\bar{\omega})}{\bar{\omega}-\omega} $$

Comment: This is a mathematical exercise from complex analysis. You should ask on a math forum. Physically, we know the Lorentz susceptibility function satisfies KK relations without having to verify this. KK relations hold for Fourier transform of any reasonable physical response function - the Lorentz model brings nothing special in this respect.

Comment: Well thanks for answering, how do we physically know that it satisfies KK without proving it?

Comment: For "any" function $f(t)$ that is zero for $t<0$, its Fourier transform obeys KK relations. Check this paper:http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5990-5266EN.pdf

Comment: @JánLalinský Thanks but I need to verify them by explicitly integrating the real part and the imaginary part.

Comment: The main ingredients are causality and passivity of the response function $χ(x,t)$. See A. Tip, Phys. Rev. E 69, 016610 (2004) for full details.

Comment: I do not see why this is off topic. By the criteria listed in the help center on topics that can be asked, this question obviously falls in the category of "Mathematics in the context of physics" as the question asks about the specific relationship resulting from Lorentz model of electric susceptibility.

Comment: @Hans Thanks for your concern. Even though not entirely mathematical physics this is related to a physical model. Could someone justify why it was marked as off topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume all the variables involved are real. The roots of the denominator of $\chi(\omega)$ are $\frac{1}{2}\Big(i\gamma\pm\sqrt{-\gamma^2+4\omega_0^2}\Big)$ which lies in the lower (upper) half of the complex plane for $\gamma<(>)0$. You need to further specify the sign of $\gamma$. $\gamma<0$ leads to the relationship in your question, while $\gamma>0$ put negative sign to the left hand sides of the relationship, and $\gamma=0$ destroys the relationship.

Suppose $\gamma<0$. $\chi$ is analytic on the upper half complex plane and by Cauchy's Integral Theorem,
$$0 = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{\chi(\bar\omega)}{\bar\omega-\omega}\mathrm d\bar\omega,$$
where the contour $C$ runs along the real axis from $-R<0$ to $R>0$ with an infinitesimally small semicircle running clockwise around and above $\omega$, then describes the large semicircle circle counter-clockwise in the upper half complex plane with radius $R$. The clockwise integral around the small circle above $\omega$ approaches $-\frac{1}{2}\chi(\omega)$ while the integral on the large semicircle with radius $R$ approaches $0$ as $R\rightarrow\infty$ as the magnitude of the integrand is $O\big(\frac{1}{R^3}\big)$. Therefore
$$\frac{1}{2}\big(\chi_r(\omega)+i\chi_i(\omega)\big) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}P\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\chi_r(\bar\omega)+i\chi_i(\bar\omega)}{\bar\omega-\omega}\mathrm d\bar\omega.$$
Equating the real and imaginary parts of the equation, leads to the desired result.

---

To explicitly verify the relationship, we use 
$$\chi_i=\frac{1}{2i}(\chi-\chi^*). \tag 1$$
The poles of $\chi$ lies in the lower half complex plane. Evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\chi(\bar\omega)}{\bar\omega-\omega}\mathrm d\bar\omega$ using the contour integral described in the general proof above and get $i\chi(\omega)$. The poles of $\chi^*$ lies in the upper half complex plane. So we evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\chi(\bar\omega)^*}{\bar\omega-\omega}\mathrm d\bar\omega$ using the previous contour reflected with respect to the real axis and get $-i\chi(\omega)^*$. Then evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi}P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\chi_i(\bar\omega)}{\bar\omega-\omega}\mathrm d\bar\omega$ using Equation $(1)$, we arrives at the desired first relationship.

The second relationship is derived explicitly similarly with $\chi_r=\frac{1}{2}(\chi+\chi^*)$.

Comment: Thanks for the through explanation but I need to do an explicit integration to get the imaginary part of the refractive index from the real part and vice versa.

Comment: @Vesnog: I have added the explicit verification. You may need to fill in the details according to my description when writing your report.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your effort I think I need to take into account 2 out of 4 of $\chi$'s poles and the pole at $\omega$. Making a total of 3 poles out of 5.

Comment: @Vesnog: It is not clear what your comment is contending. Are you trying to say you do not agree with or not understand my proof?

Comment: I did not comprehend your post previously since I did not remember Cauchy's theorem about finding the residues. We already now the explicit forms of real and imaginary parts of the complex electric susceptibility $\chi$ as a function of frequency, $\omega$. In the convention of our textbook $\omege_0 > \gamma$ and I think the relations you refer to according to the sign of $\gamma$(which is plus in our case) are the KK relations, am I right?

Comment: @Vesnog: The relation I refer to in my answer is of course the KK relation, because that is the objective of this exercise, is it not? Also $\gamma$ should take on the negative (not positive, please read carefully) sign if KK is to hold, as I have clearly stated in my answer. The first thing you ought to do then is to study the Cauchy Integral Theorem if you have not done so http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula. It will also be more efficient if you can make your questions more to the point since it is hard to discern what you are trying to get at.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will get it done after studying the Cauchy integral formula.